# Google Contacts. Does it sync avatars?

Tags: contacts, google-contacts

My family has me in their contacts app (the google one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts). If they enter my email for that contact my google account avatar will be displayed for that contact. I will probably change that avatar from time to time. The question is:
Will the avatar will be updated in a automatic way and if so how long does it take to sync?
Or maybe the avatar is imported only during manual contact creation/editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that after some time it will sync. It took few days.